# Uninstall Linux OS's with GRUB

Tags: 12.04, grub2, uninstall, mint, oss

Is there a way to uninstall my 3 Linux OS's: Ubuntu, Linux Mint and Pear OS (Pear OS's Partition somehow got formatted, just the partition, not the OS)
With GRUB so I can install everything freshly? I made a big mess and I think that I need to reinstall it freshly, I got a Linux Mint live USB in case of emergency.

The real problem is that I also got Windows 8 and I don't wanna lose any files there.

Summary: How do I completely delete My Linux Operative Systems along with GRUB to reinstall it freshly?

Comment: What about *format partitions*? [This short answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/125144/62483) will give you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

No, Grub can only load systems and control loading. Just load live session, for example there is gparted live or also create ubuntu live dvd or usb, and install gparted in live session.
In Gparted program delete ubuntu, mint ot other systems partitions, and then create new partition from free space. And don't touch partition of windows.

Comment: I see, gparted, a program to remove OS's, i'll keep that in mind, but I think that the main reason of me removing the Operative Systems is to reinstall GRUB and realocate the Operative System's boot files with more care...

Comment: If you want to reinstall grup, just use boot-repair program. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair